# How can I pass a struct to NSOperation Init

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to know how I can pass a pointer to a struct to a custom init method of nsoperation. It seems to expect to be passed an item of type ID.

Is this possible to do?

```
typedef struct mystruct

{
   int a;
   int b;

}mystruct;

mystruct myitem;


MyNSOperation *op=[[MyNSOperation alloc]initwithdata:myitem]; //can't do this, not of type id


-(id)initwithdata:(mystruct *)thestruct

{


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a struct as an object, you can use NSData

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&myitem length:sizeof(myitem)];
```

and get it back to a struct with

```
[data getBytes:&myitem length:sizeof(myitem)];
```

This is not architecture independent.

Answer (score 1):

Your init method should look like this:

```
-(id)initwithdata:(mystruct)thestruct

{


}
```

Or you should pass reference to your structure:

```
MyNSOperation *op=[[MyNSOperation alloc]initwithdata:&myitem];
```

Choose wisely.

Comment: I cant seem to define -(id)initwithdata:(mystruct)thestruct in the NSOperation Sublass header. I get a Compiler error saying "expected ( before mystruct"

Comment: Try to pass reference then `MyNSOperation *op=[[MyNSOperation alloc]initwithdata:&myitem];`

Comment: @dubbeat - Can you move the definition of the struct to the header for your NSOperation subclass or some shared header file?  You definitely can use a custom struct as a parameter for an initializer, but the compiler needs to know what it is first.